# Can someone help analyse my java code on an averaging program?

Tags: java

Hi so I've started learning java online for two weeks now, but as I watched those tutorials, I felt the only way I'd actually grasp that information was to practice it. My other programs worked great, but just when I decided to do something spectacular (for me only of course; a java expert would find creating this program mind-numbing), something went terribly wrong. I'd really appreciate if you could take a look at my code below of an averaging program that could average any amount of numbers you want, and tell me what in the world I did wrong.

UPDATE: Eclipse just outputs a random number after typing in just one number and then shuts down the program. 
[Here is a snapshot where I type in the console to average 6 numbers and then start with the number 7, but for some reason, when I hit enter again, it outputs 8.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJWOW.png)

```
package justpracticing;
import java.util.*;

public class average{
    int grade = 0;
    int average;
    Scanner notoaverage = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of numbers you'd like the average of! ");
    final int totalaverage = notoaverage.nextInt();

    Scanner averagingno = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Start typing in the " + totalaverage + " numbers");
    int numbers = averagingno.nextInt();
    int counter = 0;

    public void averagingnumbers(){
        while(counter<=totalaverage){
            grade+=numbers;
            ++counter;
        }

    }
    public void printStatement(){
        average = grade/totalaverage;
        System.out.println(average);
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't say what the error is, what you have tried to fix it, etc.

Comment: Well, you need a `main` method to begin with.

Comment: ++counter;, correct me if im wrong, but shouldn't it be counter++;?

Comment: @user3045026 There is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have created an `average` Object in another class, and are calling the methods given from a main class.

I don't know what exactly you're having trouble with, but one problem is here:

`average = grade/totalaverage;`

These 2 variables that you are dividing are both integers. That means that the result will also be an integer. This is called [truncation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation). What you want to do is first convert at least one of the integers to a double:

`... = (grade * 1.0) / totalaverage;`

You also want your `average` variable to be a double instead of an integer so that it can be a lot more accurate.

Comment: Thanks. I'll copy and paste the code in my main class and try converting those integers to doubles and see if it solves the problem

Comment: Many problems.... First of all, look at his variables. If you move everything to main, there will be a problem due to the fact the scope of the variables in main won't extend to the functions. Next, there is no loop to keep calling them.